# Generate custom properties code i VS?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, properties, code-generation

I hate writing repetitive code....

In my current project I need to write properties that looks the same in each class, but different from class to class.

My wish is to generate custom properties from private memeber variables. Lets say I have declared a Name variable like this.

```
private string Name;
```

In my first class I want to automagically generate a property like this:

```
private string m_name;
public string Name
{
get
{ return m_name; }
set
{
  m_name = value;
  // some code....e.g.
  m_counter++;
}
```

And maybe I want another implementation in my second class, e.g.

```
private string m_name;
public string Name
{
get
{ return m_name; }
set
{
  // some code....e.g.
  if(MyValidationFramework.Validate("Name", value))
  {
    m_name = value;
  }
}
```

I know I can create my own snippets. Since I often change the property-implementation I'd like a way to generate the properties from a template, then change the template and generate properties again. Can this be done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is not direct answer to you question. However, with the example you show, why not to have a base class and inherit from it, like this:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    private string m_name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return m_name; }
        set
        {
            if (BeforeNameSet(value))
                m_name = value;
        }
    }

    public virtual bool BeforeNameSet(string name)
    {
        return true;
    }
}

public abstract class ChildClass : BaseClass
{
    public override bool BeforeNameSet(string name)
    {
        // do the part that is different
        return false;
    }
}
```

**[Edit]**

I see you that snippets are not an option for you.
You could create an item template, ([How to: Manually Create Item Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247113.aspx)), but in the end this is even more effort as you want to be able to dynamically update those. Item template is a zip file, that you would need to change content for.

Seems like copy/paste is your best option then.

Comment: This is how I do it now! But it only works if the implementations is similar.

Comment: @Erik Z - you could keep the part that is similar in your bases class, and what is different in the child classes.